# How to use laravel eager loading condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel eager loading When I return the related record in the query I throw in the related table, the other records come as null, just how can I get the records matching my requirement

Here is MyCode:
[image]

Here is MyResponse:
[image]

Comment: Are you wanting to only get the `SchoolClasesBranchesPivot` where the `branches_id` = 3?

Comment: yes I just want to get the data from branches SchoolClases Branches Pivot table with branches id = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the code you have is it's limiting the relationships that are loaded rather than limiting the initial models.

To limit a model by its relationships you can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
SchoolClasesBranchesPivot::with('school', 'clases', 'branches')
    ->whereHas('branches', function ($query) {
        $query->where('branches.id', 3);
    })
    ->get();
```

---

That being said, for this specific example you could use the `branches_id` key on the pivot table itself:

```
SchoolClasesBranchesPivot::with('school', 'clases', 'branches')
    ->where('branches_id', 3)
    ->get();
```